# Error to update Android Developer Toolkit version 22

Tags: java, android, eclipse

today when opening eclipse, I get this:

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or adove
Current version is 21.
Please update ADT to the latest version

I try to update, but I get this alert:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Any idea of how to run the update?

Thanks!

Comment: did u retry updating ?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to update the ADT, I tried everything and no thing succeed to get it working again.
My advice is to download the latest [ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) again